# How can I place the bookmarks toolbar above the tabs bar on recent versions of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, user-interface, browser-tabs

I hate the way tabs are now on top, while the bookmarks toolbar is on the bottom.

Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 4):

View -> Toolbars -> uncheck "Tabs on Top".

(Works with Firefox 7.0.1 on Windows.)

Comment: This had been available since Firefox 4.0, when Mozilla redesigned the UI.

Answer (score 4):

### Firefox 3.6 default interface:

[image: Firefox 3.6]

### Firefox 9.0 default interface:

[image: Firefox 9.0]

### Getting the 'old look' back:

- **Uncheck** the following: **Firefox** > **Options** > `[ ] Tabs on Top`

  [image: Options]

  **OR...**
- If the **Menu Bar** is visible, **Uncheck** the following: **View** > **Toolbars** > `[ ] Tabs on Top`

  [image: Views]

### End result:

[image: Tabs]

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox 17.0:

1. Go to `about:config` in the navigator bar.
2. Search for key: `browser.tabs.onTop`
3. Make it false.